# Adding comma every 3 digit problem, in python, what's different using list or using format

Tags: python, algorithm, digits

I am practicing an algorithm on a website.

I want to add data(number) comma(,) every 3 digit.

But 'a', which variable I made, can't be the collect answer.

But 'b', which variable I searched, is the collect answer.

**Can you tell me why 'a' is not the same as 'b'**

```
length = 8
data = "12421421"

inv_result = []
for index in range(length):
    if index % 3 == 0:
        inv_result.append(',')
        inv_result.append(str(data[index]))
    else:
        inv_result.append(str(data[index]))

result = inv_result[::-1]

#first comma delete
result.pop()

a = ''.join(result)
b = format(int(datas),",")

print(a)
print(b)
print(a == b)
```

result is

```
12,412,421
12,421,421
False
```

Comment: What is `datas`?

Comment: Because your code shuffles the numbers around. If you look closely, one string is `'12,412,421'`, the other `'12,421,421'`.

Comment: If you had tried some other examples when testing this. e.g. `data = "12345678"` It would probably have been immediately obvious to you what was going wrong. Always try to test on a variety of data. This example looked "almost right" because the number was "almost a palindrome" which might have been confusing compared to an example that was obviously very wrong.

Comment: ow thank you! I missed that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't reverse the data in the beginning. The following (slightly cleaned up) code works:

```
length = 8
data = "12421421"
inv_data = data[::-1]
inv_result = []
for index in range(length):
    if index % 3 == 0:
        inv_result.append(',')
    inv_result.append(str(inv_data[index]))

result = inv_result[::-1]

#first comma delete
result.pop()

a = ''.join(result)
b = format(int(data),",")

print(a)
print(b)
print(a == b)
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are making it backwards with this line:

```py
result = inv_result[::-1]
```

If you didn't reverse the order, then you would have the right order.

```py
result = inv_result
result.pop(0) # remove first character which is a comma
```

But this only works if the number of digits is a multiple of three. For example, if your digits were 1234, then doing it this way would result in 123,4 instead of the desired 1,234.

So you have to reverse the string in the beginning or go through it in reverse order. Then leave the later inversion and pop() like you had it.

```py
for index in range(length):
    if index % 3 == 0:
        inv_result.append(',')
    inv_result.append(str(inv_data[-1-index]))# count from -1 to more negative, equivalent to going backwards through string

result = inv_result[::-1]

#first comma delete
result.pop()
```

Comment: That's actually not true. If you run the code without the result = inv_result[::-1] you'll see that result is `',124,214,2'`

Comment: The other problem is that it will be wrong unless the number of digits is a multiple of three.... so things are wrong in general anyway

Answer (score 0):

A solution with comprehension:

```
data         = "12421421"
len_data     = len(data)
triplets_num = len_data // 3
remainder    = len_data % 3
triplets     = [data[:remainder]] if remainder else []
triplets    += [data[remainder+i*3:remainder+3+i*3] for i in range(triplets_num)]
result       = ','.join(triplets)
print(result)
```